# Firefox and Chrome Parsing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg, highcharts

EDIT: I'm using it with an Angular controller (don't know if it matters). The error code is generated by Angular also.

EDIT2: Sometimes it errors in Firefox and sometimes it doesn't.

EDIT3: Was replicating the error, took some tries to make it appear. Below is a snippet of the error:

```
Error: String contains an invalid character
save_chart@http://localhost:8080/site/assets/app/controllers/SiteCtrl.js:1239:46
getFunction/<@http://localhost:8080/site/assets/app/controllers/SiteCtrl.js:1099:7
```

`Line 1239:46` is `image.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(svg);`.

`Line 1099:7` is `save_chart($('#chart').highcharts(),'container');`

I am using Highcharts and then I convert it to an image using the function below: [Source Here](http://jsfiddle.net/willkoehler/1p81fbzs/)

```
var chart = $('#chart').highcharts();
var target = "targetcanvas";

function save_chart(chart,target) {
    var render_width = EXPORT_WIDTH;
    var render_height = render_width * chart.chartHeight / chart.chartWidth

    // Get the chart's SVG code
    var svg = chart.getSVG({
        exporting: {
            sourceWidth: chart.chartWidth,
            sourceHeight: chart.chartHeight
        }
    });

    // Create a canvas
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.height = render_height;
    canvas.width = render_width;
    $('#'+target).html(canvas);

    // Create an image and draw the SVG onto the canvas
    var image = new Image;
    image.onload = function() {
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0, render_width, render_height);
    };
    image.src = "data:image/svg+xml;base64," + window.btoa(svg);
}
```

The problem now is that on a certain chart, it has a label that has an "and"(`&`) symbol which is converted to `&amp;` in the `Getting the chart's SVG code` part and throws an error in Firefox: `Illegal character in string` in the `window.btoa(svg)` line but in Chrome everything just works out fine.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: throws an error where?

Comment: I'm currently replicating the error. Will update soon.

Comment: Why not just do `img.src = 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + svg;` it does support SVG directly ?

Comment: The problem is with the `svg` cause it contains a unicode. `<svg>... &amp; ...</svg>`

Comment: try calling escape after btoa maybe (or before), or create a [mcve]